# Firebase RTDB REST API reconnect without sending data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have application that is composed of frontend apps and backend that communicate using firebase RTDB. Since for language we use on backend there is no SDK implementation, we use REST api. We use a lot of subscriptions on nested structure like `/chats/{user_id}/{message_id}`. Problem is that I need to process each message only once, but I can't create index on nested node, so it is not possible, for instance, to add attribute `processed` to message and then use query to subscribe only to unprocessed messages.

Another part of the problem is that when connection need restart, whole `chats` structure is downloaded again. When I was debugging `nodejs` sdk, I noticed that it is actualy using websocket and is sending some kind of subscription token on reconnect and data are not re-downloaded, but websocket is not documented for RTDB. So I would like to know if someone had this kind of problem and if there is solution without changing structure or language for backend (maybe there is some undocumented header I can use??)

I was also thinking about finding way to extend expire time of service account token (I suspect that expiration of token is reason that subscription timeout and get restarted every hour, I'm using 2 minutes timeout for keepalive). But this would by just temporary solution.